# Why the UILable will not show up before passing the value from another page?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel, segue

I am new to swift and i got some problems when i try to build an App. 
When I try to pass the value from View A to View B (but the App will access View B first), the label from B will not show up. However, if I go from View B to View A and update the value in View A and then go back to View B, the value in View B will be updated. Why will this happen?

One more question, the value changed from both view A and B will not be kept after logging out / going back to another view. How can I keep the changes even I logout / switch to another View?

Thanks all! Here is my code.

**Class View B**

```
@IBOutlet weak var num_1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var num_2: UILabel!

var labeltext = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    num_1.text = labeltext
}

@IBAction func topic1(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("contentView", sender: self)
}
```

**Class View A**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{

let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn");

if(!isUserLoggedIn)
{
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);
}


}


@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

    let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginView") as! LoginViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  //  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginView", sender: self);


}

@IBOutlet weak var voteNum1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var voteNum2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var centerCircle: UIImageView!

var num1 = 0.0
var num2 = 0.0
var sum = 0.0
var a = 0.0
var b = 0.0
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()

@IBAction func vote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    num1 = Double(voteNum1.text!)!
    self.voteNum1.text = String(num1 + 1)
    a = num1 + 1

}

@IBAction func vote2(sender: AnyObject) {
    num2 = Double(voteNum2.text!)!
    self.voteNum2.text = String(num2 + 1)
    b = num2 + 1
}

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    sum = Double(a/(b+a))
    circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // round view
    let roundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(85, 100, 150, 150))
    roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2

    // bezier path
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint (x: roundView.frame.size.width / 2, y: roundView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  radius: roundView.frame.size.width / 2.2 ,
                                  startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI),
                                  endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI),
                                  clockwise: true)
    // circle shape
    circleShape.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    circleShape.lineWidth = 14
    // set start and end values
    circleShape.strokeStart = 0.0
    circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(sum)

    // add sublayer
    roundView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    // add subview
    self.view.addSubview(roundView)
    self.view.insertSubview(roundView, belowSubview: centerCircle)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : View B = segue.destinationViewController as! View B

    DestViewController.labeltext = voteNum1.text!
}

@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("back", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I want the UILabel (num_1) in View B to be shown even before i pass the value from View A.

Comment: Moreover, I hope to store the previous updated value (num_1, num_2, voteNum1, voteNum2) even I switch to another pages(like switch from A to B, the voteNum1 in A remains unchanged. Now, it will return 0 every time.) or logout.

Comment: So basically do you want to store the values here are two scenarios.
1. For the long term, however, app kill?
2. For temporary throughout the app running

Comment: Thanks. It needs to store for long term. Any suggestion?

Comment: So basically, if you have large amount data so you have to go with a database like below answer given and If you have smaller data such user information you can use user default to store values.

Comment: Thanks @SalmanGhumsani, it's helpful.

Comment: hi @SalmanGhumsani, i just found the solution below not working. Will you able to help?

Answer (score 0):

The line in your view b;

```
num_1.text = labeltext
```

Instantiates a new string everytime.

Change the line

```
var labeltext = String()
```

to

```
var labelText : String? = nil
```

To keep data after logging out you need to develop 'persistence' into your app. Essentially you need a persistent store of data embedded within your application.

Popular ways of doing this is;

- CoreData
- Realm*

*https://realm.io

- https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ <- Tutorial for how to add persistence to your app through Realm using swift.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it seems nothing changed after I replacing the line to 
var labelText : String? = nil
when I run the app, the UIlabel(num_1) still didn't show up in the first time.